# Why is my street map in pokemon GO accurate even when GO is not out for my country?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I live in India and as everyone knows, the game is not out for my country yet.      So i downloaded a pokemon GO apk from a 3rd party website and the game is up and working on my phone. **BUT** the street map in the game is perfectly correct.  Every house, every street and every park in the game map matches my real surroundings. How can that happen when the game is not out for my country yet?

Please help

Answer (score 5):

The game simply uses the data from *Google Maps* combined with gameplay data from *Ingress*.

There's no need for them to set up anything specific for India. (Doing this by hand would be a massive task even just for one country).

Also keep in mind that often features or data are already in some game even before they're actually accessible.

Comment: if the street map is ready then why isn't the game already out for India?

Comment: @Adi Just a marketing/business decision.

Comment: @Adi their servers can't support everyone, it's constantly crashing as it is.